# ggplot violin plot is not plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to plot a violin plot with the R package `ggplot2` with the code

```
norm2 = function(v) return(sqrt(sum(v*v)))
myfct = function(d) {
  vec_length = Inf
  while (vec_length > 1){
    vec_length = norm2(runif(n=d,min=-1,max=1))
  }
  return(vec_length)
}

df = data.frame(x = rep.int(1:5, 2))
df$vec_length = sapply(df$x, myfct)
ggplot(df, aes(factor(x),vec_length)) + geom_violin(trim=FALSE)
```

but I get

```
Warning:
In max(data$density) :
  no non-missing argument for max; return -Inf
```

And my plot is

[image]

What have I done wrong?

Comment: `norm2` is a package not a function? Using `base::norm` throws an error

Comment: @FonsMA: Sorry, added the function.

Comment: @RLave: Sorry, added the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data only has two `vec_length` (y) for each `x`. This is rather a "special case" where the violin would reduce into a line. One could have implemented `geom_violin()` also as `geom_line()` in such cases, but that isn't realized like that:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df1, aes(factor(x), vec_length)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

To draw a violin you need at least three y values:

```
df2 <- data.frame(x=rep.int(1:5, 3))
df2$vec_length <- sapply(df2$x, myfct)
ggplot(df2, aes(factor(x), vec_length)) + geom_violin(trim=FALSE)
```

[image]

---

#### data

```
library("SpatioTemporal")
set.seed(42)
myfct <- function(d) {
  vec_length <- Inf
  while (vec_length > 1){
    vec_length <- norm2(runif(n=d, min=- 1, max=1))
  }
  return(vec_length)
}

df1 <- data.frame(x=rep.int(1:5, 2))
df1$vec_length <- sapply(df1$x, myfct)
```