# How do I make a violin plot with ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I'd like to make a violin plot in plotly based on a violin plot in ggplot.

I looked at this similar question, but my use case is different since I'm not getting the [same warning.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54286542/ggplot-violin-plot-is-not-plotting)

Right now, it's just showing a horizontal line without the boxplot or violin or outliers.

This is my code

```
library(fpp)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

gg <-
  credit_old %>% 
  ggplot(aes(score, y = "")) +
  geom_violin(trim = T) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.1) +
  theme_ipsum_rc(grid = "XY") 

ggplotly(gg)
```

Comment: are you able to show any of your data and how it is arranged?

Answer (score 2):

To make a violin plot or boxplot via `ggplotly` you have to map on the `y` aesthetic. Plotting with flipped aesthetics is to the best of my knowledge at present not supported via `ggplotly`. Therefore, if you want a horizontal violin or boxplot you have to make use of `coord_flip`.

Using `mtcars` as example data try this:

```
library(plotly)

gg <-
  mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = "", y = mpg)) +
  geom_violin(trim = T, fill = NA) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.1)

ggplotly(gg)
```

[image]

**Horizontal box or violin plot:**

```
gg + coord_flip()
ggplotly()
```

[image]

Comment: I noticed that when you `coord_flip()` the violin plot becomes a static image