# How do I create plots using geom_violin, geom_jitter and plotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am creating plot using `geom_violin()` and `geom_jitter()`. Everything works find using ggplot, however once I include plotly, I loose the violin shape. See below -

Plot with only ggplot -
[image]

Plot with plotly -
[image]

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong and how to fix. See reproducible code below -

```
# libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
library(ISLR)
library(plotly)

# data
data <- OJ %>% 
    as_tibble() %>% 
    clean_names()

# plot
p <- data %>% 
    ggplot(aes(price_ch, purchase))+
    geom_violin()+
    geom_jitter(aes(text = price_ch),width = 0.1, alpha = 0.5)+
    facet_wrap(~store7)
    
# plot with plotly
ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can not have your categorical feature on `y` axis in `Plotly`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64521434/10276092

Switch `x` and `y`, then use `coord_flip()` function to flip the whole chart.

```
p <- iris %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Species, Sepal.Length))+
  geom_violin(aes(color=Species))+
  geom_jitter()+
  facet_wrap(~Species)+
  coord_flip()

ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The link by M.Viking gave me the clue into this - but it's a bit more complicated than just adding `coord_flip()` because you have a `geom_jitter()`. You need to ensure that is flipped as well and change the `width` argument to `height` - otherwise you will end up jittering across the `purchase` axis, so there will still be overplotting.

```r
p <- data |>
    ggplot() +
    geom_violin(
        aes(
            y = price_ch,
            x = purchase
        )
    ) +
    coord_flip() +
    geom_jitter(
        aes(
            y = price_ch,
            x = purchase,
            text = price_ch
        ),
        height = 0.1,
        alpha = 0.5
    ) +
    facet_wrap(~store7)

ggplotly(p)
```

[image]